# I can't fix this ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error.

Tags: java

This is a the part of my code that java says where the error is.String.valueOf(Answer[i].toUpperCase().charAt(j));  I can't figure out why. can anyone please help?

```
   for (int i=0; i<=Answer.length; i++)
    {
        int IEAs=0, IEBs=0, IEdashes=0;
        int SIAs=0, SIBs=0, SIdashes=0;
        int TFAs=0, TFBs=0, TFdashes=0;
        int JPAs=0, JPBs=0, JPdashes=0;

        for (int k=0; k<70; k=k+7)
        {

            for (int j=k,p=0; j<=k+6; j++,p++)
                {
                        SevenAnswers[p] = 
         String.valueOf(Answer[i].toUpperCase().charAt(j));

                }
            switch (SevenAnswers[0].charAt(0))
            {
            case 'A':
                IEAs +=1;...
```

Comment: try changing the outer loop from i<=Answer.length to i<Answer.length.. since i starts at 0 if you iterate until i = the length of the string then i will hit an index of one greater than the final char.. thus throwing your exception.

Comment: It could be `j` variable, you should check it and make sure that `0 <= j < answer[i].touppercase().length()`. Also, you should check your `p` variable. And one more thing, you should seperate your code to many parts, so it's easier to debug 
ex: `Answer answer = Answer[i]; String answerAsString = answer.toUpperCase(); and some checking and String sevenAnswer = answerAsString.charAt(j); and then SevenAnswers[p]=sevenAnswer` it's longer than the original but you can figure out where problem is.
Edit: The outer loop should be ` for (int i=0; i<Answer.length; i++)`

Comment: why did you give k as 70 and j as k+6. Might be an issue from there?

Comment: Thank you all! I have implemented your feedback, and it seems to be working.

Comment: @Jayanth this is the instruction. (why i set K to 70 and j to increase by 6:

Comment: ... if we consider the I/E to be dimension 1, the S/N to be dimension 2, the T/F to be
dimension 3, and the J/P to be dimension 4, the map of questions and an examinee’s answers to their
respective dimensions would look like this:
1223344122334412233441223344122334412233441223344122334412233441223344
BABAAAABAAAAAAABAAAABBAAAAAABAAAABABAABAAABABABAABAAAAAABAAAAAABAAAAAA
Your program will process a test data file. The file will contain line pairs, one per examinee. The first
line has the examinee’s name, and the second has the examinee's 70 answers (all "A", "B" or "-").

Comment: example,
Betty
BABAAAABAAAAAAABAAAABBAAAAAABAAAABABAABAAABABABAABAAAAAABAAAAAABAAAAAA
Ben
aabaabbabbbaaaabaaaabaaaaababbbaabaaaabaabbbbabaaaabaabaaaaaabbaaaaabb
Han
BA-ABABBB-bbbaababaaaabbaaabbaaabbabABBAAABABBAAABABAAAABBABAAABBABAAB

"A" and "B" in the file can be upper or lowercase. A dash represents a question that was skipped.

Comment: first line of code  should be 'for (int i=0; i<Answer.length; i++)'   not not ' i<=Answer.length'